# Setting maximum and minimum values for x-axis in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have a graph that has dates on the x-axis and I'm trying to set maximum and minimum values for this axis using an Excel VBA. I defined MinXAxis and MaxXAxis values in the same sheet and here is my code:

```
Sub UpdateChartAxes()

   With ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Chart

      .Axes(xlCategory).MinimumScaleIsAuto = False
      .Axes(xlCategory).MinimumScale = Range("MinXAxis").Value
      .Axes(xlCategory).MaximumScaleIsAuto = False
      .Axes(xlCategory).MaximumScale = Range("MaxXAxis").Value

   End With

End Sub
```

When I run this code I get error 400 with no explanation about the error.
Any ideas what might be going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Axis.MinimumScale Property**

> Returns or sets the minimum value on the value axis. Read/write
>   Double.

You should be applying these properties to the value axis `xlValue`, not the Category axis.

Setting this property will also set `MinimumScaleIsAuto = False` so you won't need those lines.

**Added** If you use a column, bar, line, etc., graph then these have a Value and a Category axis. You can only set the Minimum or Maximum for the Value axis. Even if you swap them around (x - y) there is still only one Value and one Category axis. **Edited** An exception to this is if dates are used as the Category axis, in which case Excel enables the Scale settings, as it recognises them as values.

If, instead, you use a Scatter graph, then this has both X-Values and Y-Values, and each of these *value axes* can be given maxima and minima.

By far the easiest way to prove all this is to double click on an axis and see whether the `Axis Options` allows you to set a minimum and maximum.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean I need to change. I am actually setting max and min values for both axis in the graph and I've used xlValue for y-axis values and xlCategory for x-axis values. Is that wrong?

Comment: I don't know about your specific graph, but I've quoted from the Access Help system - `MinimumScale` applies to the value axis. Just logically, Categories don't have a minimum or maximum. Also, if you double-click the Category Axis, min and max values are not available for it.

Comment: @AndyG You can have `MinimumScale` and `MaximumScale` on the category/X axis if all of the values consist of dates. This shouldn't be the issue

Comment: Ah, you are right @Jaycal, my apologies. Yes, dates are an exception, as even though they occur as xlCateogory, Excel allows their Min and Max to be set, using their serial value, e.g. 41478. I'd forgotten about this.

Comment: You are right Andy, I figired I should set the data range rather than max and min values for the category axis (x-axis).

Answer (score 0):

At the beginning of the code, add

```
On Error GoTo ShowErrDescription.
```

After `End With` and before `End Sub`, add the following code

```
Exit Sub
ShowErrDescription:
MsgBox Err.Description
```

This should at least give you a little more information about the error.

Comment: Thanks for the help. It is a Compile error: Invalid outside procedure. I'm not sure what that excatly is related to?

Comment: @Jaycal Your `Exit Sub` should appear after the MsgBox, this is causing the OPs outside procedure error.

Comment: this should work fine; the invalid outside procedure is the error description for the 400 error the OP was originally seeing